# How to add days into current date?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am adding days to the current date but I am getting an invalid date in the result.

I am using BeanShellPreprocessor in Jmeter and using following code to get the current date.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.util.Date; 
Date date = new Date(); 
date.setDate(date.getDate()+15); 
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm a"); 
String formattedDate = df.format(date); 
vars.put("slotFirstCall",formattedDate);
```

This code is adding 15 days to the current date but the value I am getting in the variable is 02/33/2018. And it is showing a different date on the calendar. Date on the calendar, where I am using it is 03/05/2018.

If I use this code in Java I get the correct result, but in Jmeter I get the invalid date.

Comment: D (capitalised) means day-in-year. Today is 18th day of the year, so 18+15=33. You probably need "d" which means day of the month.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have provided unlikely implements what you expect. If you refer to `SimpleDateFormat` [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you will realise that `D` capitalised represents day of the year but not the day of the month.

Today is 18th day of the year, so `18 + 15 = 33` which does not look surprisingly.

However putting the year day "index" along with the month does not make a lot of sense and does not correspond to any known date-representation format. This makes me think you have a bug in your code.

Change your code to

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.util.Date; 
Date date = new Date(); 
date.setDate(date.getDate()+15); 
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm a"); 
String formattedDate = df.format(date); 
vars.put("slotFirstCall",formattedDate);
```

this could help.

**UPD:**

**P.S.** - It is also worth checking other specificators in your format. Revise if you really need `a` at the end of your date pattern since `a` means `AM/PM`, however you are using `HH` which represents the time in `24H` format. So `AM/PM` **does not introduce any additional value to your timestampt**.

Comment: Please see also my P.S. update

Answer (score 0):

This is really a Java-related question as opposed to a JMEter question.

That said, this link shows you how to use the Java Date classes you're using and how to manipulate the date.

[Mykong Link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-add-days-to-current-date/)

The Mykong site is a great source on Java.

Comment: Adams, The code is working fine in case of java but when I am using the same in Jmeter, showing a different result.

Comment: @AnilKumar - I edited your question to add this information.

Answer (score 0):

Since [JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) you have [__timeShift()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function which can make your life easier. The relevant function call would be something like:

```
${__timeShift(MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm a,,P15D,,slotFirstCall)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Time Shift Example]

---

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 it is recommended Groovy for all forms of scripting](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) (general recommendation of avoiding scripting where possible still applies)